# Why can't my ci-cd config file find this Ansible command?

Tags: ansible, gitlab, cicd

I'm currently testing out Gitlab CI-CD and Ansible and I wanted to combine the two. I already made an Ansible playbook which is just a small nginx server for testing.

I'm using a Docker container with an Alpine image for my runner.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - install
  - deploy

install-ansible:
  stage: install
  script:
    - apk add ansible -v

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml
```

The first part of the Pipeline is working but it always fails in the deploy part and I get the following error message:

```bash
$ ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml
/bin/sh: eval: line 128: ansible-playbook: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Comment: Stages run in separate containers. What's happening is `install-ansible` stage installs ansible in a container, then it terminates. `deploy-job` starts up another container, without ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install ansible in the same job where it is suppose to run: i.e. drop the `install_ansible` job and install ansible in `deploy-job`.

Note: as is, you'll have to install ansible in every stage where you want to use it.

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apk add ansible -v
  script:
    - ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml
```

As installing packages on each ci run (and possibly in different jobs) can be costly and lengthy, you might consider creating an image already containing ansible, push it to a docker registry and use it directly in your job instead of the default one provided by your runner config:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  image: my.docker.repo/my/ansible/image:latest
  script:
    - ansible-playbook ansible_roles.yml
```

An other solution is to ask your runner administrator to install ansible in the default image used by your runner so that it is always available by default.